# Style background of spanned words in android

Tags: android, string, textview

I'm trying to style background (color, corners) of some words in the string. I use SpannableStringBuilder in order to set spans.

I tried a few different approaches but none of them gave the exact solution.

- **BackgroundColorSpan**: I can't adjust height and corner, apart from that it is perfect. Unfortunately I don't have control over canvas while using this span.
- **LinearBackgroundSpan**: When I override canvas and add background color, it basically adds for the entire line. Somehow I don't get the correct start index.
- **ReplacementSpan** : This works perfectly but only for single line. If the line is long and needs to be wrapped, it doesn't work.

I want to achieve something like below with adding some corner and play around with the height. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this, first create this method:

```
public class RoundedBackgroundSpan : ReplacementSpan
{
    public override void Draw(Canvas canvas, ICharSequence text, int start, int end, float x, int top, int y, int bottom, Paint paint)
    {
        var rect = new RectF(x, top, x + MeasureText(paint, text, start, end), bottom);
        paint.Color = Application.Context.Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.nextTimeBackgroundColor);
        canvas.DrawRoundRect(rect, Application.Context.Resources.GetDimensionPixelSize(Resource.Dimension.localRouteDetailsRoundRectValue), Application.Context.Resources.GetDimensionPixelSize(Resource.Dimension.localRouteDetailsRoundRectValue), paint);
        paint.Color = Application.Context.Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.nextTimeTextColor);
        canvas.DrawText(text, start, end, x, y, paint);
    }

    public override int GetSize(Paint paint, ICharSequence text, int start, int end, Paint.FontMetricsInt fm)
    {
        return Math.Round(MeasureText(paint, text, start, end));
    }

    private float MeasureText(Paint paint, ICharSequence text, int start, int end)
    {
        return paint.MeasureText(text, start, end);
    }
}
```

And do this:

```
var stringBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
var stringToAppend = "hello world";
stringBuilder.Append(stringToAppend);
stringBuilder.SetSpan(new RoundedBackgroundSpan(), stringBuilder.Length() - stringToAppend.Length, stringBuilder.Length(), SpanTypes.ExclusiveExclusive);
```